# Channels and Wait Groups Entering Deadlock

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm having trouble wrangling go routines and getting them to communicate back to a channel on the main go routine. To simplify, my code looks something like this:

```golang
func main() {
    channel := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go performTest(channel, &wg, i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(channel)

    for line := range channel {
        fmt.Print(line)
    }
}

func performTest(channel chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, i int) {
     defer wg.Done()
     // perform some work here
     result := fmt.sprintf("Pretend result %d", i)
     channel <- result
}
```

This seems to enter into some kind of a deadlock, but I don't understand why. It gets stuck on `wg.Wait()`, even though I would expect it to continue once all the goroutines have called `Done` on the wait group. What am I missing here? I'd like to wait for the goroutines, and then iterate over all results in the channel.

Comment: You are waiting before reading off the channel - https://go.dev/play/p/EnbfKe_d-BL

Comment: Cheers, putting the wait after works, but I don't understand why I can't wait before reading off the channel?

Comment: The thing is that an unbuffered chanel must be written/read from different goroutines. In your example, if you make the channel buffered as `channel := make(chan string, 10)` no deadlock would happen. A better option is to run the write or read part into its own goroutine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wait for the group and close the channel in a separate go routine. If the channel is closed, your range over the channel will end after the last sent value has been received.

If you just wait, nothing will receive from the channel. Since the channel is unbuffered, the `performTest` goroutines won't be able to send. For an unbuffered channel, the send operation will block until it has been received. Therefore, the deferred `wg.Done` call would never happen, and your program is deadlocked. Since `Done` is only called after the forever-blocking send has been performed.

```
func main() {
    channel := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go performTest(channel, &wg, i)
    }
    
    // this is the trick
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(channel)
    }()

    for line := range channel {
        fmt.Print(line)
    }
}

func performTest(channel chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // perform some work here
    result := fmt.Sprintf("Pretend result %d\n", i)
    channel <- result
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/5pACJzwL4Hi

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for your help. Am I correct in saying that if you don't provide a length to the channel, it can only buffer a single value at a time, so like you say, after the first has written into the channel, no more can write until the buffer has been read?

Comment: One more question: is there not a risk of a race condition if the final go routine that runs the `performTest` function calls `Done` on the wait group, then the anonymous function in main proceeds to close the channel before all data has been read from the channel buffer in the main go routine? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: you are right, its not as I said. If you buffer you could still read from the channel all the message. Only after the last message has been recieved, the channel is shut down. I have taken that paragraph out as it was incorrect. It wouldnt make much sense if it behaved like that.

Comment: So you can read from a closed channel (I think is what you are saying)?

Comment: you can read from a channel that you gave as argument to the close function. It will be only really closed after the last value has been recieved. `... has the effect of shutting down the channel after the last sent value is received.` So its kind of buffering the closing of the channel to the end of all sent messages.

Comment: @テッド Your theory in the first comment isn't entirely correct. For a unbuffered channel there's no buffer i.e., if you are sending to a channel, it is expected that receiver is also ready to receive it. Think of it as a pipe where in one end the writer has put his hand inside it to give some data to the receiver and on the other end receiver hand is also inside the pipe ready to receive it. Sending to a channel without a receiver would lead to a deadlock.

Comment: @shmsr we are talking about what happens if you call close on a channel before you have read the last message. Yes the buffering works like that. But you can read all messages even if you have already called close. For example if you buffer 10 messages and then call close, before you have read the 10 messages, you still can read all of them.

Comment: Right. I see what you saying. That there is no buffer not even of 1 for an unbuffered channel. But I think @テッド did also not mean it like that. It was more to describe how it behaves. You can sent 1 message in and as long as it hasnt been read, your next sent will block until it has been read.

Comment: And additionally you cannot sent to it before there is a receiver. Good point, I will correct that in my answer.

Comment: Somehow my one comment got deleted :/ @TheFool glad to help \o/

Comment: @shmsr doesnt this mean in my answers code, it could still technically end up being a deadlock? If the first goroutine manages to write before the range has begun?

Comment: but this doesnt seem to be the case https://play.golang.com/p/qR-JLZqestj. I put a sleep before the read to ensure the first goroutine tries to write, but it still works.

Comment: @shmsr thank you for your input. That helps to understand why an unbuffered channel will cause a deadlock. As you say, you absolutely need to have a receiver ready to accept the channel write.

Comment: @テッド it doesnt seem like you need to have a reciver ready at the time of writing. See my playground from the comment above. It seems like it will just block at the time of writing until its being read.

Comment: This shows it even better https://play.golang.com/p/gaXtqi3uJ89 @テッド.

Comment: Basically, a receiver is ready (or eventually ready in a separate goroutine). Read: https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/10/the-behavior-of-channels.html. Basically guarantee of delivery is important.